# Why does this compile? The code seems to be breaking constraints on the type parameters

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, eclipse-jdt, compiler-bug

In the following test, TesterClass places a constraint on the relation between its two type parameters. The method func2() seems to break that constraint, and I expect it to cause a typing compilation error somewhere (on func2's definition, or whenever the class is used with any second parameter other than String), but it doesn't!

Furthermore, if I call func2 and save the result in an appropriately typed variable, the compilation fails (on the type of that variable). But doing the same and saving in a more general type (such as Object) succeeds, despite the fact the the function's return type should have the same type in both cases (before the up-cast).

What's going on here?

Thanks!

```
public class TestGenerics {
    public static class ParamedType<T> {}


    public class TesterClass<A extends ParamedType<B>, B> {
        public TesterClass<A, B> func() {
            return new TesterClass<A, B>();
        }

        public TesterClass<A, String> func2() {
            return new TesterClass<A, String>();
        }
    }

    public Object test() {
        // How can I use these type parameters? Doesn't .func2 now have an invalid return type?
        TesterClass<ParamedType<Integer>,Integer> testClass = new TesterClass<TestGenerics.ParamedType<Integer>, Integer>();

        //TesterClass<ParamedType<String>, Integer> res2 = testClass.func2(); // <-- will not compile
        Object res = testClass.func2(); // Compiles
        return res;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: This *doesn't* compile in javac (versions reported below). I'm using Eclipse, and trying to find out what's the compiler that's actually running. Will update. May be a JDT (Eclipse compiler) bug.

I've opened a bug report for eclipse's jdt:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333503

Comment: Doesn't compile for me, `javac 1.6.0_21`.

Comment: Does compile under Eclipse compiler at Java 6.0 compliance level

Comment: There's a missing brace at the end of the code, but it still does not compile (via javac in JDK 1.6.0_20).

Comment: Missing brace is a formatting error. (Fixed)

Comment: I believe the Eclipse compiler is part of the "JDT Core Component" and includes incremental compilation functionality. http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/

Comment: Could be a JDT bug, here's my JDT Version: 3.6.1.r361_v20100714-0800-7z8XFUSFLFlmgLc5z-Bvrt8-HVkH
Build id: M20100909-0800

Comment: Actually, to make sense, you should change "TestGenerics<...>" in the commented out line to "TesterClass<ParamedType<Integer>, String>".  The class `testClass` has a type parameter `A` of `ParamedType<Integer>`.  To make sense, the type for the left-hand var `res2` should have the same type parameters as func2 (`A` => `ParamedType<Integer>`, `B` => `String` - in the commented out line, `String` and `Integer` are swapped.). The line still won't compile, but I think the test makes more sense with those changes.

Comment: Bert F, the problem is that it DOES compile at all (with that line commented out). Apparently an Eclipse bug, I'm trying to find out.

Comment: @sinelaw - I get the issue.  I tried your code and I get the same problem.  I uncommented the commented out line to try it and it flagged several (other unrelated) errors.  You attempted to receive the result of func2() into a variable with a different type than func2() - for example, the raw type of `res2` is `TestGenerics` which is *not* your generic class `TesterClass`. These problems are incidental to the problem at hand, but I wanted to point out the typos.

Comment: Tested with `javac 1.7.0_21`, and fails compilation (as expected)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: it doesn't compile, at least under javac 1.7:

```
Test.java:10: type parameter A is not within its bound
    public TesterClass<A, String> func2() {
                       ^
  where A,B are type-variables:
    A extends ParamedType<B> declared in class Test.TesterClass
    B extends Object declared in class Test.TesterClass
Test.java:11: type parameter A is not within its bound
        return new TesterClass<A, String>();
                               ^
  where A,B are type-variables:
    A extends ParamedType<B> declared in class Test.TesterClass
    B extends Object declared in class Test.TesterClass
2 errors
```

You didn't say what you were compiling it under - my guess is that your Java compiler has a bug in it.

Comment: I just tested with javac 1.6.0_23 and it doesn't compile, indeed.

Comment: By the way, it's been over two years since I reported this issue on Eclipse and it's still not fixed. One would think that enforcing type safety would rank high on the criticality scale of a Java compiler...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is an Eclipse bug in JDT.core. I've opened a bug report at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333503